# How to reshow gtk.Image after window.hide&show?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

As you can see it this example, if we close and then show again window that contain gtk.Label - label is showing too, but if window contain gtk.Image - we could not see it.

```
import gtk,gobject

def dest(*a):
   print 1
   gobject.timeout_add(1000,dest2) 
#also, why it is impossible to show window again at once it closed?


def dest2(*a):
   print 2
   win.add(child)
   win.show_all()
   shild.queue_draw()
   print 'where is is?'

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect('delete-event', dest)
l = gtk.Label('gtk')

image=gtk.Image()
f=fopen('some_image.png','r')
loader = gtk.PixbufLoader()
loader.write(f.read())
loader.close()
f.close()
image.set_from_pixbuf(loader.get_pixbuf())

child=image
#child=l  #so, if uncomment this string - everything is perfect
win.add(child)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

@scythargon

What is shild.queue_draw()? Anyway:

```
def dest2(*a):
   print 2
   image.set_from_pixbuf(loader.get_pixbuf())      # <<<---- add this "and your hair will be soft and silky"
   win.add(child)
   win.show_all()
#   shild.queue_draw()
   print 'where is is?'
```

and my pygtk says:   loader = gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader()

> #also, why it is impossible to show window again at once it closed?

You may try to use "return True" in dest()